# EF Core: How to have models with different names from the tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a database-first application with tables that have different names from my models.  My application worked fine using fluent API until I added a model that had a one-to-many relationship with another model.  It then started giving me the error:

> SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such column: a0.AuthorAuthorId

Sample classes would be:

```cs
class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Author Author {get; set; }
}

class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

and my OnModelCreating is -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
        .ToTable("tbl_Book")
        .HasKey(b => b.BookId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
        .ToTable("tbl_Author")
        .HasKey(a => a.AuthorId);
}
```

I tried using `.HasOne()` and `.WithMany()` to specify the relationship between the tables. That did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined and configured a foreign key property, so EF is looking for one with its own naming convention. To avoid the issue add a foreign key property in `Book` model -

```cs
class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public Author Author {get; set; }
}
```

and configure it manually by adding the following code to `OnModelCreating` method -

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
        .HasOne(p=> p.Author)
        .WithMany(p=> p.Books)
        .HasForeignKey(p=> p.AuthorId);
```

Comment: I'm so used to EF figuring out the foreign keys on it's own I stopped including them in my models.
I completely missed the fact that EF would need to be told how to link the models if the names were different.